# Broken animation with stagger, group and sequence

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

[Description and bug walk-through available on Stackblitz (see Project>INFO)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-sw7kwd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

### Goal

Given the following template:

[div 1 and div 2 stacked in a parent div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JSGk.png)

Animate the following sequence for the parent div's DOM entrance:

- 100 ms from each other, the children div:

  - *Step 1:* go from dark cyan to light green (1 s)
  - *Step 2:* flash in light blue (250 ms)

### Constraint

The blue flash implementation must be nested in a group()

### Suggested implementation

```
animations: [
// parent animation
trigger('stagger', [
  transition(':enter', [
    query('@color', [stagger(100, [animateChild()])]),
  ]),
]),

// children animation
trigger('color', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({
      'background-color': 'darkcyan',
    }),
    animate(
      '1s ease-out',
      style({
        'background-color': 'lightgreen',
      })
    ),
    group([
      sequence([
        animate(
          '125ms',
          style({
            'background-color': 'cyan',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '125ms',
          style({
            'background-color': 'inherit',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]),
]),
]
```

### Bug

*Step 1* does not work. The color is stuck on the end color (light green) during the whole step.

### It works correctly when

- The **constraint** is ignored (the flash sequence is written directly, no group/sequence).
- The parent animation is removed and the children animations are run simultaneously
- The flash targets the text color instead of the background color

### My thoughts

I have no idea what's going on. Help?

Comment: looks like an angular animations bug

Comment: A bit unsettling... The animation doesn't seem especially intricate... 
Thank you for your comment!